# How to Set Every Attributes and Methods of Class Attribute to Become Class' Attributes and Methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

So, I have a logCreator class like this

```py
import logging,logging.handlers

class LogCreator:

    _logLevel = {
        "NOTSET": 0,
        "DEBUG": 10,
        "INFO": 20,
        "WARN": 30,
        "WARNING": 30,
        "ERROR": 40,
        "CRITICAL": 50
    }

    def __init__(self,logFile,
                      level='DEBUG',
                      verbose=True,
                      maxBytes=1024*1024,
                      logFormat='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'):

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(logFile)
        self.logger.setLevel(self._logLevel[level])
        logger_formatter = logging.Formatter(logFormat,
                                             datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logFile, maxBytes=maxBytes, backupCount=1, encoding="UTF-8")
        file_handler.setLevel(self._logLevel[level])
        file_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        if verbose:
            console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            console_handler.setLevel(self._logLevel[level])
            console_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)
            self.logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

class `LogCreator` has attribute which is `logger` so if I want to do some logging I have to do this

```py
l = LogCreator('logfile.log')

# some script
l.logger.info('I just did something')
```

I felt like it looks kinda ugly and nonintuitive and would be better if I could write

```py
l = LogCreator('logfile.log')

# some script
l.info('I just did something')
```

So, every attributes and methods from `logger` attribute of class `logCreator` would be that class attributes and methods. I tried by `return self.logger` at the end of initialization of class but it raise error because `__init__()` has to return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add some method to do. Like this:

```
class LogCreator:
    """ your init code"""

    def info(self, message):
        self.logger.info(message)

    def debug(self, message):
        self.logger.debug(message)
```

Then you can use:

```
logger = LogCreator('./out.log')

logger.info('info')
logger.debug('debug')
```

Or. you can only add one method to return the logger:

```
def get_logger(self):
    return self.logger
```

Then use:

```
logger = LogCreator('./out.log')

log = logger.get_logger()

log.info('info')
log.debug('debug')
```

Comment: The first solution could be done but it is kinda exhausting to write every method. The second solution isn't direct and I feel like set another variable is kinda wasting space?

Comment: You mean this?  `logger = LogCreator('./a.log').get_logger()`.